# Letters in native mode seem too small on my monitor

Tags: resolution, monitor, lg

I have a problem. I have a lg monitor flatron w2242s and my graphic card is Nvidia GT 220. Native resolution for my monitor is 1680x1050, but when I use that resolution it feels like "sand" in the eyes because letters are too small and have like "points", but if I choose for example 1024/768 screen is blurry, I've installed Nvidia drivers but didn't help ¿what can I do?

Comment: perhaps you can post a screenshot of what it looks like. are you using the nvidia proprietary drivers?

Comment: Thank you,I've already fixed it, I donwloaded Nvidia Drivers and changed the Hz of the monitor,it was the problem. Thank you and greetings from Argentina.

Comment: glad you sorted it out - you should add your solution as an answer to your question and accept the solution. that way future visitors to the site will know how you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded Nvidia drivers (proprietary) and changed the Hz of the monitor to 60 from the Nvidia Panel,that was the problem. Thank you all.